# Misaligned table on privileges page

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface

The privileges and the percentages do not line up on https://stackoverflow.com/privileges. They seem to be misaligned by about half a line.

Edit:

I'm seeing this in IE7.

Comment: +1 I can confirm that I also get this when using IE7 at work; but note that when I'm at home on FF3.6 they are correctly placed.

Comment: I have no idea, what you are talking about. And I tested it in FF, Chrome and (eeh!) IE. Shoot it, or it never happened.

Comment: @Ladybug, +1 for pics-or-it-didn't-happen on principle, but I have reproed and will add screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, in my original draft I did include the browser version, but must have lost it when I changed the wording, will edit to make it clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're starting to put IE7 in our "we will guarantee the site works, but there may be visual inconsistencies from time to time that you would not experience in a more modern browser" bucket.

As long as the site works, we aren't fixing cosmetic issues with IE7 any more.

Comment: Cheers Jeff, unforunately I'm forced to use IE7 by corporate policy. Hopefully the more sites begin to have issues, the more likely they are to change...

Comment: @James, it's IE7 having issues, not the sites.. Anyway, argue to your policy makers by security. Using IE7 is a security risk. Smuggle some IE7 nuke in your intranet site and they will change mind quickly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Reproed with IE 7 on Win XP, but **no** repro with FF 3.6 on the same computer.

[image: the first "0%" is almost a full line below "access to moderator tools"]

Comment: Is this really a site problem, or an IE problem, given that IE tends to render some pages poorly? Never mind, it is becoming clear.

Answer (score 0):

You guys should be a little bit more precise with your browser version:

[image]

## I CANNOT REPRODUCE IT!

Comment: Sorry, I saw "IE7" in a comment and forgot that the question body didn't specify a browser. Will update screenshot/edit main post.

Comment: I would +1 if you'd use the "About" dialog as a ruler to show the aligned-ness of the two blocks

Comment: @Pekka: Freehand-lines is the only way to go! Your idea would force me drawing circles around the About box. Have I already mentioned, that I suck at freehand circles? On the other hand, I do things I suck at all the time ...