# Badges -> Publicist Badge

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges

Steps to Replicate:-

1. open stackoverflow page
2. click on "Badges" on the Top
3. click on "Publicist" badge (only 1 fellow has got that)
4. The display is not proper. Vertical scrollbar not visible properly.

Comment: No-repro in FF 3.6. and Konqueror 4.4.2 under Ubuntu. Can you perhaps tell us what browser you are using? (Also, is there a particular reason why there are these four steps to reproduce, rather than just [a single link](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist)?)

Comment: Browser is IE7. I can still see the issue. Yes you are right, the navigation link is http://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist.

Comment: If yo use IE7, layout glitches are your problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68213/misaligned-table-on-privileges-page/68278#68278

Comment: No-repro on IE8.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer - That explains it...thanks..

Comment: The very concept of that badge is astounding. That was setting the bar pretty high.

Comment: @MPelletier: the bar is even higher if you consider that currently you [can't get Publicist on your first or second try](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67398/), even if the numbers say that you qualify.

Answer (score 3):

We're starting to put IE7 in our "we will guarantee the site works, but there may be visual inconsistencies from time to time that you would not experience in a more modern browser" bucket.

As long as the site works, we aren't fixing cosmetic issues with IE7 any more.

Comment: And Amen for that. Stupid IE..