# A few problems with IE7

Tags: support, bug

I see a few bugs with IE7. One is that the "upload image" box does not work (see [Browse button in Image insertion doesn't work in IE7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77675/browse-button-in-image-insertion-doesnt-work-in-ie7)). The buttons are out of place and "Browse" does not work correctly, so I cannot upload images.

- [Example of the browse button being broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jBz.png)

Also, on /privileges pages (like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges), the percentage column is shifted down and does not align correctly with the name of the privilege.

- [The privileges column not displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdvKw.png)

I'm using IE 7, version 7.0.5730.13.

Comment: IE7 is only minimally supported: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported/71208#71208 - In other words bugs that don't affect asking, answering, and voting on questions are sometimes declined.

Comment: Oh, I see. The "upload image" feature is a rather important piece of functionality, though.

Comment: Well, it's really just a timesaver so you don't have to go to Imgure and upload manually. Not *that* important. (Speaking as someone with IE8, which it doesn't work well with either.)

Comment: So, this is merely a duplicate of the two other questions you linked?

Comment: @mmyers, it also prevents "image rot", as the SE Imgur account is a non-expiring pro account.

Comment: @Arjan: I've only posted images on Meta, so I never gave the image rot problem any thought. Good point.

Comment: (That being said, @mmyers: Flickr pro accounts [are not that safe](http://www.observer.com/2011/tech/flickr-accidentally-deletes-users-4000-photos-and-cant-get-them-back) either. Or maybe [they are](http://www.observer.com/2011/tech/flickr-restores-mirco-wilhelms-3400-lost-photos-and-really-really-sorry-about).)

Comment: @Arjan I've only linked one question, which was about the image dialog box, and it did not explain the problem well. The items in the list boxes are images (they are large so I didn't do inline images). And yes, the image rot issue is why I bring it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Misaligned table on privileges page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68213/misaligned-table-on-privileges-page) (My bad, I thought you actually linked to another question for the alignment issue too, but you didn't. A dupe though.)

Comment: @Arjan oh... this seems to happen every time I find a bug: I search for it and don't find anything relevant and then it gets closed as a duplicate of something I missed. I must suck at searching.

Comment: Or I spend too much time here, remembering things that were already posted ;-)

Comment: Above all: your image is used well at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77675/browse-button-in-image-insertion-doesnt-work-in-ie7 now!

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorere 7 is [explicitly not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/167443), so it looks like your options are upgrade your browser, or live with the bugs.